# Firefox: why is the Awesome Bar forgetting my web history?

Tags: firefox, browser, firefox-profile, awesomebar

I've been a very happy user of the Awesome Bar in Firefox. Basically it used to let me find any webpage if I remembered its title (even if I didn't remember the URL). I was always able to find any article that I ever visited in the past, even years ago.

However, it looks like the Awesome Bar is not so awesome anymore, at least it seems to be forgetting stuff that I hadn't visited for a few weeks. It doesn't even auto-suggest my favourites anymore, unless I visited them recently. I'm not sure if this is a result of an update. I don't use any add-ons that could use this. (I use HTitle, JSONView, Markdown Viewer and Adblock Plus, and I don't think any of these would cause this.) I run Firefox on the latest Fedora, but I don't think my platform of choice should affect this.

Is there a way to return the Awesome Bar to the way it originally worked, ie. remember everything?

Comment: Entirely unrelated: I suggest you try uBlock Origin instead of Adblock Plus.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to [refresh Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/refresh-firefox-reset-add-ons-and-settings). It creates a new profile and copies relevant data from the old profile. The old profile is moved to your desktop to backup or delete as desired.

> ### What does the refresh feature do?
>
> All of your Firefox settings and personal information are stored in a profile folder. The refresh feature works by creating a new profile folder for you while saving your important data.
>
> Add-ons which are normally stored inside the Firefox profile folder, such as extensions and themes, will be removed. Add-ons stored in other locations, such as plugins, will not be removed but any modified preferences (such as plugins you have disabled) will be reset.
>
> #### Firefox will save these items:
>
> - Bookmarks
> - Browsing history
> - Passwords
> - Open windows and tabs
> - Cookies
> - Web form auto-fill information
> - Personal dictionary
>
> #### These items and settings will be removed:
>
> - Extensions and themes, website permissions, modified preferences, added search engines, download history, DOM storage, security certificate and device settings, download actions, plugin settings, toolbar customizations, user styles and social features will be removed.

Go to `about:support` (can’t be linked here, unfortunately) and select “Refresh Firefox...” in the upper right.

Unfortunately, Firefox profiles are still somewhat prone to corruption, especially when you use the browser a lot.